# Comparison without deriving Ord

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

My prof asked us to implement bubble sort in Haskell.
The problem should be easy, however, he specified the function signature like this

```
bsort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
bsort = undefined
```

The problem is that a is not deriving `Ord`, so I have no idea how to compare `a`s. So I wonder if this is doable or he forgot to add `(Ord a) =>`?

Comment: Not deriving `Ord` is the reason why the function has an explicit comparator `a -> a -> Bool`.

Comment: `bsort` as shown is  a generalization of `bsort' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`. The comparison function is an explicit argument, rather than inferred from the `Ord` instance of `a`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is doable, no he did not forget. Here's a hint:

```
bsort (<=) = undefined
```